# When using tomcat pooled datasource in springboot I get No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource'

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, datasource

I'm trying to use pooled tomcat datasource with spring boot only by specifying properties in application.yml file as follows :

```
spring:
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        enabled: true
  datasource:
    tomcat:
      max-active: 50
      max-wait: 10000
      username: postgres
      password: root
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/proj
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I get

`Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).`

I don't understand why springboot is trying to create an embedded datasource.
Is that the expected behavior for a pooled datasource ?

I saw on some forums that spring-jdbc dependency can cause this issue so I excluded every spring-jdbc dependency. No I get

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory
.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
```

POM file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.yyyy.xxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>xxxx</name>
<description>xxxx project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jsoup.version>1.10.3</jsoup.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<organization>
    <name>SA Technologies</name>
    <url>www.satechnologies.com</url>
</organization>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>${jsoup.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.jpdigital</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-hibernate-5.1.2.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <dialects>
                    <param>POSTGRESQL9</param>
                    <param>SQLSERVER2012</param>
                </dialects>
                <packages>
                    <param>com.yyyy.xxxx.model</param>
                </packages>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/docs/sql</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>gen-ddl</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.yyyy.xxxx.persistence.repositories" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.yyyy.xxxx.persistence.model" })
@Configuration
public class PersistenceConfig {

}

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.yyyy.xxxx" })
public class XxxxApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(XxxxApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(XxxxApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help please ?

Comment: Can you upload your configuration & POM file?

Comment: Add this dependency and let me know: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: I have added it but I still have the exception :
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "local" are currently active).

I have added a local profile and made it active by default. The exception text is misleading me...

Comment: Check this: http://mrbool.com/rest-server-with-spring-data-spring-boot-and-postgresql/34023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct setup is

```
spring:
  profiles.active: local
  data:
    jpa:
      repositories:
        enabled: true

  datasource:
    type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    username: postgres
    password: root
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/proj
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    tomcat:
      max-active: 200
      max-age: 1000
      max-wait: 10000
      removeAbandonedTimeout: 30
      initial-size: 20
      validation-query: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    database: postgresql
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

These 4 properties sit under datasource, not tomcat.

```
  username: postgres
  password: root
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/proj
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Take a look at `DataSourceProperties` here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java

Further reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties

Comment: These properties do exist under tomcat property. So this is not the reason.

Comment: Maybe so, but in terms of the exception you posted, the tomcat properties don't matter.  What matters is that the spring.datasource.* properties are at least minimally set.  This exception `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException` is being thrown on this line https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java#L245.  Also don't exclude jdbc libs that are automatically included within the spring-boot-starters.